# Best practice/pattern for user authentication at init time in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I'm building the login functionality for an Angular SPA. All of my login/logout functionality is encapsulated in a service named AuthService (which, in turn, wraps a few $resources). The user is considered to be "logged in" if their browser has a valid PHP session cookie.

I have everything working, except for one thing: determining at init time whether the user is already logged in.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
angular.module( 'MyModule', [ 'ngResource', 'ngRoute' ] )
    .run( [ '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthService', function( $rootScope, $location, AuthService ) {

        /**
         * Initialize AuthService. This will cause it to make a REST call
         * to GET /api/current_user. That endpoint will return either a JSON
         * representation of the logged-in user, or a 401 Unauthorized.
         * Either way, AuthService will cache the results, which can be
         * accessed by calling AuthService.getUser().
         */
        AuthService.init();

        /**
         * Listen for route changes. If the user tries to change to a route
         * that requires login, but the user isn't logged in, then redirect
         * to the login page.
         */
        $rootScope.$on( '$routeChangeStart', function( event, next, current ) {

            if ( next.$$route.requiresLogin && AuthService.getUser() === null ) {
                $location.path( '/login' );
            }

        } );

    } ] );
```

Obviously, there's a problem here: the call to `AuthService.init()` will take time to complete (since it must make an HTTP call), but the first `$routeChangeStart` event will fire as soon as `.run()` completes.

So, even if the user is already logged in, `AuthService` won't know that yet, and the user will get "redirected" to the login page.

I could tweak AuthService.init() to return a promise, and refactor this code accordingly:

```
angular.module( 'MyModule', [ 'ngResource', 'ngRoute' ] )
    .run( [ '$rootScope', '$location', '$route', 'AuthService', function( $rootScope, $location, $route, AuthService ) {

        /**
         * Initialize AuthService. This will cause it to make a REST call
         * to GET /api/current_user. That endpoint will return either a JSON
         * representation of the logged-in user, or a 401 Unauthorized.
         * Either way, AuthService will cache the results, which can be
         * accessed by calling AuthService.getUser().
         */
        AuthService.init(
            function() {

                // Make sure the user is allowed to view the initial route
                enforce_login( $route.current );

                // Also check when the user tries to navigate to another route
                $rootScope.$on( '$routeChangeStart', function( event, next, current ) {
                    enforce_login( next );
                } );

            }
        );

        function enforce_login( theRoute ) {
            if ( theRoute.$$route.requiresLogin && AuthService.getUser() === null ) {
                $location.path( '/login' );
            }
        }

    } ] );
```

However, this is problematic too: if the HTTP call to `GET /api/current_user` takes a second or two to complete, and the user has loaded a protected route, then the app will briefly display the protected route, before redirecting to the login page.

What I really need to do is *delay* loading/rendering of the initial route until AuthService has had a chance to determine the user's login state.

Is there a typical approach to this problem? All of the Angular authentication tutorials I've seen assume that your AuthService will be able to *synchronously* determine the user's login state. But they don't really explain how it's supposed to do that.

One solution is to eliminate the need to make an asynchronous call in the first place. For example, I could load my AuthService from a separate `<script>` tag, like this:

```
<script src="MyModule.min.js"></script>
<script src="AuthService.js.php"></script>
```

...and `AuthService.js.php` would dynamically generate a JS file which already knows at Angular init time whether or not the user is logged in.

However, this feels really hackish—it couples the client-side app to the server-side implementation, makes AuthService.js uncacheable, and is generally a kludge.

So, my question is: how can I best check the user's login state at Angular init time, *before* Angular evaluates and renders the initial route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
resolve: { AuthService: 'AuthService' }
```

(or resolve anything else that returns the promise from auth service)  as a dependency for all access-controlled routes, see [the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when).

Listen for [$routeChangeError](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeError) to redirect to login route.

Comment: This worked well for me; thanks. For future readers: this approach doesn't use .run() at all. Instead, it uses the "resolve" option of ngRoute's .when() method. Any promises passed to "resolve" must be satisfied before Angular will switch to the route. As such, it's a perfect place to do things like auth checks. As a bonus, this makes the auth check inherently lazy-loading: it won't make the REST call until the user actually tries to switch to a protected route.

Comment: Right, that's the main reason for the app with global init dependencies to use the router even if it doesn't use routing much. No more promise spaghetti in controllers.